# how to search sqlite database record using for loop android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to loop through sqlite database if (johnny) is present in the database or not but my code is not working

```
if(!cursor.isAfterLast()) 
{
    do 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++)
        {
            if("johnny" == cursor.getString(1))
            { 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "string found!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }                   
    } 
    while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }       
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: why can't you use where in sqlite query itself.

Comment: pozzo can you show me how i can use sql? do you mean wildcard like

Comment: @Jack to use where,see below answer.

Answer (score 5):

For comparison use `.equals()` i.e. change

```
if("johnny" == cursor.getString(1))
```

to

```
if("johnny".equals(cursor.getString(1)))
```

**Edit**

You may use where query like this

```
 Cursor objCursor = db.query("yourtableName",null, "columnName=?",
            new String[] { "johnny" }, null, null, null, null);

 if ((objCursor != null) && (objCursor.getCount() > 0)) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "string found!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Note:** Replace `yourtableName` with your table name  and `columnName` with table's column name.

Comment: What is the difference between cursor.getString(1); and cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Columnname))? Why to use later and not the previous one?

Comment: @PDWaghela in getstring(1) = the value of the 1st column and getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Columnname)) = the value of the Columnname of the row.

Comment: Well then Why should one use the getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Columnname)) and not the Simple cursor.getString(1).? What the difference? is their any performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to used equal method instead of == to match string in java . or you can create query instead of doing and fetching and comparing in for loop. Like select * from table name where name like something